# Apache Beam Jupyter Notebook: ImportError: cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, jupyter, apache-beam

I'm trying to import storage into a jupyter notebook on Apache Beam kernel but it says unknown location. If I try importing other google-cloud libraries such as bigquery or datastore it works, the storage one is the one failing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue and here is how i resolved it.

1. Use `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`
2. Restart the kernel in order to use updated package

I followed above steps and now able to import.

[image]

Comment: I did that but now I saw my problem with your screenshot. I was using !pip insead of just pip, so I was installing the package in the anaconda environment instead of the apache beam one.